# Unable to create react, Abort Installation yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm having trouble to create npx create-react-app .

➤ YN0009: │ core-js@npm:2.6.11 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/logfile-10088VPjTiMAhqTi1.log)

➤ YN0009: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.12#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.12&hash=77dfe6 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/logfile-10088GGXEekcVAsh7.log)

➤ YN0009: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.6.4 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/logfile-10088HJnNDOaZdPmT.log)

➤ YN0009: │ core-js@npm:3.6.4 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/logfile-10088nbZGburV304n.log)

➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 17.86s

➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 49.26s

Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding tutorial\raraa_react has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.

i also used the yarn cache clean and npm cache clean --force.
But nothing is work. Pls help me.

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install node
npm install -g yarn
yarn cache clean
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

check if this file 'C:\Users\your user name\.yarnrc' is not hidden.

it helped me.

[image: how to uncheck a file as hidden on windows]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yarn so try cleaning cache.
`yarn cache clean` this way worked on my end.

Comment: Its `yarn cache clean` :)

Comment: Thanks, Omar. Fixed!

Comment: This solution has already been posted.

Answer (score 0):

try re-installing or updating node and npx. That should do the trick.

Comment: it work after delete the npm file from AppData and reinstall the npm install -g npx. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

for me this was causing me some issues, so I completely uninstalled yarn and yarn globally and this worked

```
npm uninstall yarn
```

then:

```
npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Then you can reinstall yarn again.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, but not exactly the same.
My error is: cra-template@npm:1.1.2 isn't supported by any available linker

This is yarn problem with new option (PNP, pack node_modules folder into zip)

I solved this by editing yarn configuration file.

Windows: C:\Users\USER\.yarnrc.yml

In this file (even after reinstal whole node) i have (don't know why): nodeLinker: nodeLinker

I check this new option PNP (nodeLinker: pnp), but react is not compatible with this.

So i changed this to - nodeLinker: node_modules

And now is everything ok.

Answer (score 0):

just update your latest npm or yarn package like that :

npm install --global yarn

Comment: This answer has already been posted

Answer (score 0):

try to update the node version to latest /curremt version , it works in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors on yarn install command and what worked in my case was to clean the `C:\Users\USER\.yarnrc.yml`

And then:

```
yarn cache clean
```

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest LTS Node js version [from here](https://nodejs.org/en) and then try command `npx create-react-app myappname`